# android open 123 flash chat in webview

Tags: android, flash, webview

i'm trying to open http://server-mychating.com/client/htmlchat/123flashchat.html in web view in android that's my code:

```
public class WebViewFragment extends SherlockFragment {

private String url;
WebView webView;
public static final String URL_ARGUMENTS = "url arguments";

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_webview, container, false);

    final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(view.getContext(), "", "جاري التحميل...",true);
    webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);  
    webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().getJavaScriptEnabled();
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            if(pd.isShowing()&&pd!=null)
            {
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    this.url = getArguments().getString(URL_ARGUMENTS);
    webView.loadUrl(this.url);

    return view;
}
```

}

but it get not found error in the webview but i tried it in android browser it worked fine 
does i have to enable something else to play flash chat ?

i did put the permissions

Comment: What error you are getting ?

Comment: i don't get error in logcat but in web view it says not found the requested url /client/htmlchat/123flashchat.html was not found on this server additionally, a 404 noy found error was encountered while trying to use an error document to handle the request

Comment: Is this file uploaded on your local server ? If yes then make sure the file is availble on the server.

Comment: no it not in my server and it worked on android browser

Comment: Does your app have the INTERNET permission?

Comment: Can you share the code that you are using to load the URL?

Comment: i did used the internet premission

Comment: Dear @user2989381 , did you solve this problem?